# Remove database-side accents with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a method that receives a string, does the search and returns all data that is the same as the word that I passed, like this:

```
public async Task<List<ProductDto>> GetAllAsync(string name)
{
    IEnumerable<Product> lstProducts = new List<Product>();

    lstProducts = await _productRepository.GetAsync(c => c.Name.StartsWith(name));

    return ProductMapper.Mapper.Map<List<ProductDto>>(lstProducts);
}
```

I have a function that removes accents Utils.RemoveAccent (string word) I can perfectly remove the name parameter exemplified above, the problem is that in the bank the word is with an accent, for example I passed as a search for the word 'ingles' and in the bank there is a record as 'Inglês', how can I use this method that I did, inside my lambda above?

ps: I tried something like:

```
listProducts = await _productRepository.GetAsync(c => Utils.RemoveAccent(c.Name).StartsWith(name));
```

GetAsync:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> 
  predicate)
{
    return await _dbContext.Set<T>().Where(predicate).ToListAsync();
}
```

[image]

But it didn't work.

Comment: You didn't post any EF-related or even data-related code

Comment: Because I think there is no need, since what I want is just to remove the accents on the side of the database, to compare with the string passed by parameter

Comment: As for removing accents, 1) why? Why not use an accent-insensitive collation instead and 2) matching is controlled by the *server's* collation. Assuming you use EF, `StartsWith` is translated to `LIKE 'abc%'` whose behavior is controlled by the column collation

Comment: Again, without any data-access code, it's impossible to provide concrete help, onluy guesses. What you posted here may not even translate to a SQL query - we have no way of knowing what `_productRepository` is or what `GetAsync` does. Perhaps it's a thin "generic" repository (a problem in itself)` and `GetAsync` is really an alias for `Where(..).FirstOrDefault`? Or is it just an alias for `Where()`? If so, its behavior depends on the column's collation

Comment: It was just a suggestion, which I thought at the time, if you have any other way of comparing ignoring accents in words, help is welcome

Comment: The docs [discuss EF Core, collation and case-sensitivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/collations-and-case-sensitivity). While you can use `UseCollation` or `EF.Functions.Collate` to specify a different collation, this prevents the server from using any existing indexes built using the original collation, resulting in a full table scan. The collation specifies the equality and sorting rules that are used to build an index. That's why an index built using one set of rules is useless with other sets

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos added GetAsync

Comment: So it *is* just an alias for `Where`. Using a low-level, single-entity "generic" repository on top of a higher level multi-entity DbContext is an *anti*pattern that breaks DbContext's Unit-of-Work and disconnected operations.

Comment: For your specific problem, how to perform efficient searches using a different collation, the only solution for most database products is to have a different computed column with a different collation and add it to a new index. At least in SQL Server, it's not possible to create an index using a different collation from the column's

Comment: CosmosDB allows case-insensitive/accent-insensitive indexing no matter what the original collation is, but the perf characteristics (extra CPU/space consumption, less than expected performance) suggest it's creating and indexing a separate column too

Comment: Trying to "remove" the accents is the worst option possible - it can't benefit from indexes because you have to compare the *result* of the normalization function, when the index was created using the original data. It would be more expensive than using eg `LIKE 'abc%' COLLATE latin1_general_ci_ai`

Comment: I already use this collation, as you can see in the image added

Comment: You use `AS`, which is Accent-*Sensitive*. To get the result you want you need `AI`, Accent-*In*sensitive